# Drawing Custom Context Menus Anywhere on Desktop

Tags: linux, qt, contextmenu

I'm trying to figure out a way to draw a context menu *foo* at the cursor's current position no matter where on screen it is (i.e. over a window that has nothing to do with my program), and I can't seem to find a clean way of doing this, as all the libraries I can find define context menus upon the current window.

The things that come to mind for me are:
A: Drawing a tiny window at the cursor and then immediately opening up a context window
B: Drawing borderless windows that act like context menus
C: Drawing directly to the root window
However, none of these seem like clean and portable solutions, so I figured I would ask before diving into code.

I know that this is not what context menus were designed for, but the look fits my application very well. I would prefer to use Qt to keep things portable across systems, but at the moment I really only care about X on Linux.

Edit: 1st paragraph expansion

Comment: How do I ask a good question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea because, in order to get mouse events from outside your own windows, you'd need to capture mouse input.

Comment: @RobbieE That's fine with me, this is a personal project. I plan on drawing the context menu upon an event determined by my program, so I don't have to worry about capturing the mouse input at any time. Also context menus seem to be written to deal with capturing the mouse outside of their host window anyways. as they often leave the bounds of the host window ([example](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/upload-to-mega.jpg))

Comment: @AnanthaRajuC How would you recommend I improve my question? I read through that link and also the one [here](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) for advice after your post, but I'm still not sure where I could improve. I'm not looking for code per say, just a point in the right direction.

Comment: I don't understand your example. The context menu was created by right-clicking on a file abd the menu popped up over the same window. How is this "outside" the window?

Comment: @RobbieE Sorry, that was poorly phrased. The context menu appears partially outside the bounds of the window (so the right side and bottom in this case) and can still handle the mouse there, so I was hoping that that would be somewhat transferable to a context menu totally outside the bounds of its window.

Comment: In `Qt`, you can pop a context menu up anywhere with the `QMenu` class but you must pass it a location. If you want to track your pointer position outside any of your windows, you need to capture the mouse pointer.